# Book, commentary, or other source that explains the Biblical usage of "compass" directions

Tags: hebrew, etymology

IIRC, there may have been a M.Y. question that referred to a source that explained the Biblical usage of the 4 directions. I.e. it explained **why**:

- קדם is East
- ים is West
- נגב is South
- צפון is North

for example:

Genesis 13:14:

> וַֽיהוָ֞ה אָמַ֣ר אֶל־אַבְרָ֗ם אַחֲרֵי֙ הִפָּֽרֶד־ל֣וֹט מֵֽעִמּ֔וֹ
>   שָׂ֣א נָ֤א עֵינֶ֙יךָ֙ וּרְאֵ֔ה מִן־הַמָּק֖וֹם אֲשֶׁר־אַתָּ֣ה שָׁ֑ם
>   **צָפֹ֥נָה וָנֶ֖גְבָּה וָקֵ֥דְמָה וָיָֽמָּה׃**
>
> And the LORD said unto Abram, after that Lot was separated from him:
>   ‘Lift up now thine eyes, and look from the place where thou art,
>   northward and southward and eastward and westward;

These terms are used in many places in Tanac"h. I know that the first 3 has other words that are sometimes used, but the ones that I listed are the main ones that I am interested in, for now.

I pretty much understand on my own why these terms are used, but I am looking for a source to explain this further. (If I don't understand what the source states, I may follow up with a separate question.)

In the verse above, it looks like geographical terms of the land of Israel were used for the directions, and they are not "generic" to other areas. E.g. - יָֽמָּה means "seaward" and it just happens to be that in Israel, the sea is in the west. Similar things can be said about the other directions except for צפון which means, "hidden". It's not a description of the land geography as far as I can tell.

I'm seeking a source that explains why these words were chosen or what the significance is.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually multiple words for each of the four directions. I wrote [an essay](https://ohr.edu/this_week/whats_in_a_word/7117) about this which I think helps clarify the issues involved. Here's what I wrote:

> The Bible (Genesis 28:14) relates that when G-d blesses Jacob and
>   tells him that his descendants’ population will “burst forth” in all
>   four directions, He uses the following words to refer to those
>   directions: yam (west), kedem (east), tzafon (north), and negev
>   (south). However, in another context (Deuteronomy 3:27), when G-d
>   tells Moses to gaze upon the Holy Land from which he was barred from
>   entering, He tells Moses to look at all four directions: yam, tzafon,
>   mizrach (east), and teiman (south). In essence, while the words for
>   west and north remain the same, the Bible uses two different words to
>   mean east (kedem and mizrach) and south (negev and teiman). What is
>   the difference between these synonymous doublets? This matter actually
>   becomes quite complicated upon the realization that the Hebrew
>   language has three words for every one of the four directions!
>
> As we shall see below, the different words for the four directions
>   focus on different aspects of those directions and are generally based
>   on either the movements of the sun or certain topographical
>   characteristics of the Holy Land.
>
> Rabbeinu Bachaya explains that the word yam literally means “sea”, and
>   is also used to refer to the west because the Mediterranean Sea lies
>   at the west side of the Holy Land. The west is also called ma’arav
>   because as the sun sets, the shapes of shadows become mixed up
>   (me’urav). Thirdly, the word acharon, which literally means “last”,
>   also means west because it is the last place along the horizon where
>   the sun is located before setting in evening.
>
> There are three words for east: mizrach, kedem, and panim. Mizrach is
>   related to the word zarach (shine) and refers to the direction from
>   which the sun first shines in the morning, while kedem is related to
>   the word kodem (early or forward) and refers to the fact that the
>   rising-sun first shines from the east. The word panim (literally,
>   “facewards”) also means east because when Adam was created the front
>   of his bodyfaced eastward.
>
> As mentioned above, the common Hebrew word for north is tzafon. The
>   commentators offer several explanations for the etymology of this
>   word: Some compare the word tzafon to tzafun which means “hidden”
>   because in the northern parts of the world (i.e. the Arctic zone) the
>   influence of the sun is “hidden”, as the cold temperatures there
>   obscure the sun’s warmth. Alternatively, because the sun generally
>   remains south of the celestial equator, the north side is considered
>   “hidden” from the sun’s presence. Others claim that tzafon is related
>   to the word tzifiya (gazing) and refers to the fact that one can
>   determine north by gazing towards the Heavens and following the
>   Northern Star. Another approach argues that the word tzafon refers to
>   Mount Tzafon (identified by scholars as Jebel Aqra on the border
>   between modern-day Turkey and Syria, a mountain mentioned in the Bible
>   which lies due north of the Holy Land.
>
> The Talmud sometimes uses the Aramaic word estan to mean north (e.g.
>   Ketubot 23a). Rabbeinu Bachaya (1255-1340) proposes that the word
>   estan may be related to the Aramaic word asuta, which means “health”,
>   and alludes to the fact that the north-wind possesses certain healing
>   properties (see Yevamot 72a). In fact, some people have a custom of
>   exclaiming “Asuta!”(“Gesundheit!”in Yiddish) when hearing another
>   sneeze, so as to bless him with good health.
>
> The word darom means south, and the commentaries explain that darom is
>   a portmanteau of the words derech yom (“the path of the day”), because
>   the sun generally remains in the southern hemisphere of the celestial
>   map during the day. The south is also called negev (literally, “dry”)
>   because the southern part of the Holy Land is a dry and arid
>   desert-land.
>
> There are two more words for north and south which you might be
>   familiar with from another context: teiman/yemin (right) and smol
>   (left). The Bible uses the words right and left to refer to the south
>   and north, respectively. This understanding presupposes that eastwards
>   is one’s frame of reference, because, as we mentioned above, Adam was
>   created facing eastwards. Therefore, because one facing eastwards
>   encounters north to his left and south to his right, the very words
>   for north and south can be left and right. In an interesting
>   geographical anomaly, the Hebrew words for left and right are found in
>   place-names near the Gulf of Aden between Africa and Arabia. One
>   travelling northwards in the Gulf of Aden will approach Yemen (related
>   to yemin) on his right, and Somalia (related to smol) on his left.

SOURCE: *[What's in a Word?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/whats-in-a-word)*, "[Looking Four Directions](https://ohr.edu/this_week/whats_in_a_word/7117)" by Rabbi Reuven Chaim Klein

Comment: Why is back related to the sun but right and left and front relate to Adams position? They all have nothing to do with either. East was just the conventional fundamental direction that all are based on. Modern cultures use north for that but one is not better or worse.